# when i'm comparing two double values that i got from TextView

Tags: android

it is not working even when the condition is true, else block is always executing.

Note: `firstnum` variable is a String.

```
double a =  Double.valueOf(result.getText().toString());
if (Double.parseDouble(firstnum) >  a ) {
        result.setText("First num is greater");
else{
        result.setText("First num is smaller");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should know what is the difference between Double.valueOf and Double.parseDouble :

`parseDouble()` returns a primitive double value.

`valueOf()` returns an instance of the wrapper class Double.

and to compare to numbers of Wrapper Class Double you should compare them like this :

```
Double a = 1.33;
Double b = 2.33;
if(a.equals(b)){
    //do something
}
```

otherwise, using == will compare object pointers ( addresses of a and b )

P.S: it will check if they are the same object not for equal values.

now to solve your problem replace the first line by this:

```
double a =  Double.parseDouble(result.getText().toString());
```

so that when you compare `a` and `firstnum` by `==` operator you will comparing values and not address pointers because they are double primitive type and not `Double` Wrapper Class